# Angular2 http get method returns empty _body

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am building an app with Ionic2 and it sends http request to the server. However, I get `Unexpected end of JSON input` on one of http request. (Other requests do not have this problem)

I did not change any code, but it suddenly started giving this error. (It worked well until last week)

As seen below, if I do same request on POSTMAN, it returns the response like in the image. What would be the problem? What do I need to do?

**Code**

```
var url = this.API_URL + 'api/program/information';
this.http.get(url).map(res => {
    res.json();
}).subscribe( isloggedin =>{
});
```

[image]

[image]

**EDIT:**
When I remove all cookies from broswer, it works in the first time, then does not work from second trial.

Answer (score 0):

It should be,

```
var url = this.API_URL + 'api/program/information';
http.get(url).map(response => response.json())
.subscribe(isloggedin => this.isloggedin =isloggedin);
```

Comment: I get on error on `response.json()` part because response is empty. As you can see in the first image, _body is empty.

Comment: do you need to pass any headers? did you alter api? there is no issue with the request

Comment: Thats what i am saying. I did not alter api. As I mentioned, other http get request on the server works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I use Angular 7 and all my requests are empty. I copy the urls in browser and all is fine.

The problem is that my C# Core2 app on the server does not accept to send content to a host that is not registred. Instruct your server to allow origin host from your domain:

**In case your server is Core2:**

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("fiver",
                policy => policy.WithOrigins(
                    "https://otb.expert"
                ));
            });
        }
   }
```